# How to check if machine is on local network (bourne scripting)

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to write a bourne script that will use the ruptime command in order to check if a certain machine is on the local network. Here's my code so far:

```
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 machine-name"
    exit 1
fi

ruptime | cut -f1 -d " " | more
```

This does what I want in the sense that the ruptime command will run and cut will parse just the machine names that are on my local network, leaving behind the rest of the information normally outputted by ruptime. What I need is to write a flow control statement (or perhaps a loop would be more elegant?) that will iterate through the list of hosts provided by ruptime/cut and determine whether the hostname given to the script as a command line argument is on the local network. Here's some chicken scratch pseudocode to help illustrate the algorithm I have in mind:

```
# if host is listed on local network (check ruptime list)
# then return true 
# echo "host is on local network"
# else return false
# echo "host is not on local network"
```

Can anyone help? I'm also open to other ideas....

Comment: You are so close, `ruptime | cut -f1 -d " " | { if grep -q "^$1"; then echo "$1 is on local network"; else echo "$1 is not on local network"; fi }`. I voted to reopen, your question is clear -- the other didn't know that `ruptime` was a BSD utility that Debian still packages.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is a tons of ways to achieve your goal and there are a few dozen ways to do it in a simple and efficient manner. One of which is using grep as it is suggested by @David C. Rankin in the first comment. However, I want to show how it can be done using a loop as you have suggested.

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts_list=$(ruptime | cut -f1 -d" ")

for host in ${hosts_list[@]} 
do
        if [ "$host" = "$1" ] 
        then
                echo "Host $1 is up"
                exit 0
        fi
done

echo "Host $1 is down"
```

Comment: Arrays are a Bash feature, the OP specifically asks for a Bourne shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

`ruptime | grep machine-name` # machine-name is actually hostname